# Output arrays in list format in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm having some difficulties outputting some data. The format of the data looks like the below:

[Click here for Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNqWE.png)

You can see that each object in the array has a **matchday** key, **awayTeam** key, **homeTeam** key and a **result** key. Other than the *matchday* key the rest all have an array as a value.

Below is my React Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import FixtureList from '../components/league-fixture-list';

class LeagueFixtures extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            <h2>Fixtures</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {this.props.leagueFixtures.map((fixture, index) => {
            return <FixtureList matchday={fixture.matchday} awayTeam={fixture.awayTeam} homeTeam={fixture.homeTeam} key={index} result={fixture.results}/>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  leagueFixtures: state.LeagueFixtures
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LeagueFixtures)
```

I want to match up each of those items. **So, for example the first item of the *awayTeam* array matches up with the first item of the *homeTeam* array and the first item of the *result* array.**

Is this possible to achieve in React? At the moment my current code is doing this:

[Click to see current frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK4j7.png)

Thank you :)

Comment: Include your fixture data **as text** in the question itself. Don't use screenshots for code and data. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use the index to pass through the team in each array?

Example:

```js
  {
    this.props.leagueFixtures.map((fixture, index) => <FixtureList matchday={fixture.matchday} awayTeam={fixture.awayTeam[index]} homeTeam={fixture.homeTeam[index]} key={index} result={fixture.results}/>);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer without knowing what is in your `FixtureList` component. However, I would guess that you are creating 10 panels (a `Fixture` component???). You'd need to make sure you are calling the indexed value from the homeTeam and awayTeam arrays rather than the entire array when constructing each `Fixture`/Panel.

Comment: `import React from 'react'


const FixtureList = (props) => {
 console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="col-sm-4">
      <li className="list-group-item">
       <span className="badge"> {props.matchday} </span>
       <div className="clearfix"></div>
        <li>{props.awayTeam}</li>
      </li>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FixtureList;`

Comment: It looks like `FixtureList` is what I imagined `Fixture` would be (i.e. a single panel). In that case it looks like @woolm110's answer is the way to go, pass the indexed home/awayTeam directly into `FixtureList`